# How do I ONLY return the value from my DynamoDB table?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm trying to return a value from an attribute in my dynamodb table. The code for the REST API is below. The return value I currently get is {"N": "101"}. How Do I get the return value to be 101? Before I added in `count = response['Attributes']['Visits']` the return value also included the metadata.

```
import boto3
import json

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = dynamodb.update_item(
        TableName='ResumeCounter',
        Key={
            'Site': {
                'N': '0'
            }
        },
        UpdateExpression='SET Visits = Visits + :inc',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':inc': {'N': '1'}
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
    res = dynamodb.get_item(
        TableName='ResumeCounter',
        Key={
            'Site': {
                'N': '0'
            }
        },
        ProjectionExpression='Visits',
    )
    count = response['Attributes']['Visits']
    return count
```

Comment: Can you provide example of `response` object?

Comment: Hi! The response now shows the value I would like as @shubham Jain answered. Before it would show  {"N": "101"}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the output from the update response object use

```
count = response['Attributes']['Visits']['N']
return count
```

and to get from get_Item use

```
count = response['Item']['Visits']['N']
```

Comment: Thank you!! This works. Now, I cannot remove the quotations. I have attempted to use the json .strip and replace function, but I still see the quotations. Do you know of any web resources that I can view to learn how to remove the quotations?

Comment: its because it is represented as string just typecast it to int and it will work. You can wrap it around like int(count)

Comment: It worked!!!! thank you! I cannot believe how many similar questions I've come across through googling without seeing your answer!